# Hyperledger Fabric: How to implement username/password authentication

Tags: authentication, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have created a business network in Hyperledger Fabric V1.1 using composer.

I have multiple participants and each participant has identity. Now I have created an angular application where the user should be authenticated using `Username` and `password` as based on the type of participant the UI needs to change.

Every user has their own `card`.

I would like to know how to implement authentication using `username` and `password`.

Comment: see more in the docs https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html - you'll need to choose your PassportJS auth strategy for authentication and follow what the strategy advises (usually a link on the right)

Comment: I am working on a very similar use case. Any leads or challenges you have encountered would be very helpful.

Comment: I would suggest using third party authentication like aws cognito or SAML2

Answer (score 1):

this is not something you will be getting out of the box so it will require some creative thinking.

one way would be to use a membership system of some kind and link it to identities.

The flow could be like this:

1. you create an identity and get all certificates required.
2. a UI user is created in your membership system
3. a link between the username and identity is created so when the user logs in, you already know which identity you use and then you know which UI parts to show or hide.

Something like this would work well, you just have to remember to deal with this link between UI usernames and Hyperledger identities, which could be some admin type of work done once when the UI user is created for the first time.

Comment: Could you help me understand on how to create link between username and identity. Do I have to store the `card` file for every user? or just store the `security key` with username in a separate mongodb and when the user logs in just fetch the security key? Pls excuse this is totally new concept for me.